# Core Data: nil managed object context on my managed object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using 2 managed object contexts for efficiently important a large data set in the background. I'm ensuring I'm only using 1 managed object context at a time in the thread.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];

MetricType *metricType = [self metricTypeForName:self.metricName fromContext:context];

NSLog(@"metric context %@", [metricType managedObjectContext]);

[self processDataInContext:context forMetric:metricType];
```

In the snipped of code above, the NSLog correctly prints out the address of the managedObjectContext i'm using. I then go on to processDataInContext - which is just a private method to interate over a json data array and add objects. Each object has a relationship to the MetricType.

However, when I go to associate them

```
metric.metricType = metricType;
```

I get the error: Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'metricType' between objects in different contexts.... even though I'm ensuring I don't do this.

When I do a log output before this line:

```
NSLog(@"My Context %@", context);
NSLog(@"metric context %@", [metricType managedObjectContext]);
```

The metricType context returns nil!!

How has it become nilled? I didn't nil it and this seems to be the reason its complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
[context reset];
```

..was being called every 50 records, which of course was removing my metricType object from the context and I wasn't re-fetching it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you initialize metricType looks fishy. What does [self metricTypeForName:fromContext:] actually do to return a MetricType instance? Are you creating a new MetricType using [[MetricType alloc]init]? I suspect you are returning something in an auto-release pool

Comment: No, there is nothing fishy going on. I use standard core data fetch to fetch an object from the store and if it doesn't exist I create it using standard core data techniques. Anyway, my answer is below: I was resetting the context.